# Как ускорить сравнение при поиске файлов дубликатов?

Tags: python, алгоритм, циклы

```py
import sys
import os


def get_all_files(dir):
    path_f = []
    for dirs, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for f in files:
            if not f.startswith("."):
                path = os.path.join(dirs, f)
                path_f.append(path)
    return path_f


def are_files_duplicates(file1, file2):
    return os.path.basename(file1) == os.path.basename(file2) and os.path.getsize(file1) == os.path.getsize(file2)


def find_duplicates(dir):
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        print("Такой директории не существует")
        return None
    path_f = get_all_files(dir)
    for counter_1 in range(0, len(path_f)):
        for counter_2 in range(counter_1+1, len(path_f)):
            if are_files_duplicates(path_f[counter_1], path_f[counter_2]):
                    print("Файл {} дублируется с файлом {}".format(path_f[counter_2], path_f[counter_1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        find_duplicates(sys.argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        print("Укажите название файла")
```

Сейчас `find_duplicates` работает за квадратичное время – сравнивает каждый файл с каждым. Как это можно ускорить?

Comment: Отсортировать и сравнивать по списку. O(n log n) вместо O(n^2).

Comment: @Harry, спасибо, воспользовался Вашим решением.

Answer (score 2):

Файлы с `одинаковым` размером `НЕ являются дубликатами`. Например два файла, содержащие `"1"` и `"2"`, будут одинаового размера, но не будут дубликатами.
Для правильного определения дубликата, надо вычислять `хэш`.

```
import os
import hashlib

def find_duplicates(folder):
    duplicates = {}
    for dirs, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for name in files:
            file = os.path.join(dirs, name)
            file_hash = hashlib.sha1(open(file, 'rb').read()).digest()
            dup = duplicates.get(file_hash)
            if dup:
                try:
                    duplicates[file_hash][name].append(file)
                except KeyError:
                    duplicates[file_hash][name] = [file]
            else:
                duplicates[file_hash] = {name: [file]}
    return duplicates

if __name__ == '__main__':
    duplicates = find_duplicates('12')
    for h in duplicates:
        for file in duplicates[h]:
            if len(duplicates[h][file]) > 1:
                print('Файлы дубликаты: {}'.format(', '.join(duplicates[h][file])))
```

out:

```
Файлы дубликаты: 12\1.txt, 12\dr\1.txt, 12\sr\1.txt
Файлы дубликаты: 12\3.txt, 12\sr\3.txt
Файлы дубликаты: 12\2.txt, 12\sr\2.txt
```

структура файлов:

```
c:\SCR\lr2\12\:
    1.txt = "1" 
    2.txt = "2" 
    3.txt = "1"
c:\SCR\lr2\12\dr\:
    1.txt = "1"
    3.txt = "5"
    4.txt = "3"
c:\SCR\lr2\12\sr\:
    1.txt = "1"
    2.txt = "2" 
    3.txt = "1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать однопроходной алгоритм (O(n) по времени, O(n) в памяти), если создать отображение: критерий уникальности -> файл.

Из функции `are_files_duplicates()` в вопросе, следует критерий уникальности:

```
key = lambda path: (os.path.basename(path), os.path.getsize(path))
```

Во многих задачах, в качестве критерия уникальности файла, можно рассматривать его содержимое (хэш содержимого), к примеру: [`key = md5sum`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7829499/4279).

Чтобы найти все дубликаты в заданном дереве директорий (`rootdir`) согласно заданному критерию (`key`):

```
import os
import contextlib


def find_duplicates(rootdir, *, key=None, suppress=contextlib.suppress, seen=None):
    if key is None:
        def key(e):
            return e.name, e.stat(follow_symlinks=False).st_size
    if seen is None:
        seen = {}  # key -> entry
    for entry in os.scandir(rootdir):
        with suppress(OSError):  # ignore I/O errors
            if entry.name.startswith('.'):
                # skip dotted paths (both directories such as .git and files)
                continue
            elif entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):  # directory
                # recursive call
                yield from find_duplicates(entry.path, key=key, suppress=suppress, seen=seen)
            elif (entry.is_file(follow_symlinks=False)  # ordinary file
                  and seen.setdefault(key(entry), entry) is not entry):
                # found duplicate
                yield seen[key(entry)].path, entry.path
```

Пример использования:

```
import sys

for a, b in find_duplicates(sys.argv[1]):
    print(a, "<->", b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответы замечательные и правильные, но у каждого есть недостатки:

- Поиск дубликатов по размеру работает быстро, но не точно
- Поиск дубликатов по хэшу работает точно, но довольно медленно

Если задача будет упираться в скорость, то можно совместить оба метода:

1. Сначала найти потенциальные дубликаты файлов по совпадению размеров
2. А потом уже только для наборов файлов одинакового размера считать их хэши и выявлять среди них истинные дубликаты

Эффективность того или иного метода в итоге будет зависеть, конечно, от того, какого размера в среднем файлы и у многих ли файлов совпадает размер.

Comment: Хорошая идея! Ещё при подсчёте хешей можно читать только первые N байт файла.

Comment: @MaxU Была у меня и такая идея. Но дело в том, что файлы с диска читаются блоками, невозможно прочесть несколько байт с диска быстрее, чем читается целый блок. Поэтому если уж читать файл, то уж весь, а раз прочли, то считать и хэш. Но так то, если заморачиваться, то да - можно ещё промежуточный вариант сделать с чтением первого блока из файла. )